# Regular expression to get a strings depending on the length of a substring

Tags: python, regex

Can you please suggest if it possible and how to define regular expression for the next problem:

I have 2 'binary' strings joined by a delimiter. Let's say the delimiter is always 3.

Example of input data:

```
11000031000111011001101111
0111000301000111011001101111
001310001110110011011110
```

On the right part of the delimiter, I need to select all '1+' blobs, but I don't want to select 1+ blobs with length equal to 1+ blobs on the left part of the delimiter.

So for example on this input:

```
11000031000111011001101111
```

There are these 1+ blobs:

```
left: 11
right: 1, 111, 11, 11, 1111
```

I would need to select all right 1+ blobs, but the '11', since those are also present on the left.

So on that example I would need to match: `1,111,1111`

Other examples:

```
0111000301000111011001101111 ==> 1,11,11,1111
001310001110110011011110     ==> 111,11,11,1111
```

I also need to have location of each string (Match Object). It is important to understand complexity of this task and if it is possible to construct FSM. What if limit the size of left part (for example < 8)

Comment: Since part1 contains 0, how could any valid string – i.e. those without 0 – from part2 possibly equal it? Is the delimiter always 3? Are the non-0, non-delimiter characters always 1? Why are you trying to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: I have modified your answer to add more detail, from what I have understand from your original text.

If it fits your requirements, we could re-open it. If not, feel free to modify it as required to give more details or correct it.

Comment: @Julio Your modifications are correct. Please re-open it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem Oleg. I voted to reopen, but we still need 2 votes more

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew, perhaps you may consider re-open this question. I think It is clear now :)

Comment: I'm still not seeing why this is a task restricted to regex. This seems to be very straightforward to do using string methods, ``itertools.groupby``, and similar. Perhaps making the expected output an *actual* expected output, including the alleged "location of each string (Match Object)", would clear that up.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want to understand complexity of this task and if it is possible to construct FSM

Comment: I would be very suprised if this is possible with regex. This is very much not possible with a regular language, and while you can use lookaheads which are not actually  regular I don't think you can do this with backreferences and lookaheads. You might need a context-free grammar.

Comment: @mousetail what if I limit the size of left part?

Comment: So, are you looking for a regular expression/language solution, or are you looking for a regex/``re`` solution?

Comment: I am looking for both: re solution and theoretic: if it is possible in general to do in regular expression/language.

Comment: That's not what I meant: regex/``re`` is more powerful than regular languages. Just because something can be parsed using ``re`` doesn't mean an FA/FSM can parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specifically ask not for only a regular expression, but a finite state machine, I can specifically prove the impossibility. In a finite state machine, you must have some finite number `n` states. We need a state for every length of sequence of `1`s found on the left side of the 3. Since we can have infinitely many possible lengths of sequences of `1`s, it is impossible to encode this information in finitely many states.

If you specifically limit the size of the left part, you effectively limit the maximum size of a sequence of `1`s. This makes it possible, though still not practical.

Suppose the size on the left is `n`. You would need a state for every possible combination of lengths of 1 that appear, which is `O(2^n)`. Good luck writing a regular expression for that. You would probably effectively end up enumerating most possible combinations and use very little of the actual state machine logic.

Example state machine for `n=4`: Note more than 16 states, and this is only the left side. Each "accepting" state here would need more complex logic to match the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be doable with regexes (which are more powerful than regular languages, as stated on the comments). But for that we would need the regex engine to support varying length look-behinds.

Unfortunately, most regex engines only support fixed-length look-behinds.

However, one could 'reverse' the original string so that look-behinds would become look-aheads (which can be varying-length)

This regex should work for reversed strings:

```
(?<!1)(1+)(?!1)(?=\d*3)(?!.*3\d*(?<!1)\1(?!1))
```

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/g1UFpH/1/).

Bear in mind that on the demo the strings have been reversed.

This is how the regex works:

```
(?<!1)(1+)(?!1)   # a blob of ones, capture it. Cannot match slices of the blob
(?=\d*3)          # must be followed by some '3'
(?!               # must not be followed by:
    .*            #   any prefix
    3             #   then a '3'
    \d*           #   then some numbers
    (?<!1)\1(?!1) #   and then a blob of ones equal to the captured one
)
```

Or course, this may be out of the 'spirit' of the original question, since it requires to reverse the input string.

However, I think it is still valuable because in theory one could make a similar regex without reversing the string, if using a regex engine that supports varying length look behinds.